# Inductor not behaving even close to calculation

Tags: inductor, inductance

I wrapped a coil around a 1/2 inch X 6 inch pure iron rod.  The coil is composed of #22 enameled copper and about 393 turns.

393 turn coil around a 0.5 inch (6 inch long) supposed pure iron rod:

[image]

This theoretically should measure 807 mH.  It only measures 3.2 mH.

I tested the meter on known inductors and it tests correctly - in other words, I believe the meter to be accurate.

Any advice or insight would be greatly appreciated (as to why the theoretical does not match the physically observed inductance).

I am trying to make an electromagnetic energy harvester to power an LED near power lines (I work on them for a living also.)

[image: Calculations]

[image: Simple Inductor/Inductance Formula]

You can also see behind the meter a 3 ft 1100 turn coil around a 1 inch steel rod.  This also does not give any sort of decent inductance (14 mH.)

An 1100 turn coil around a 3 ft X 1 inch steel rod:

[image]

Comment: What do you get if you set the DE-5000 measuring frequency to 120Hz?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany it is set to 120 Hz in the photo(s).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *This theoretically should measure 807 mH. It only measures 3.2 mH!*

There are two significant problems. The first: -

Iron is a pretty good conductor, not as good as silver of course but, within the coil it acts like a shorting turn and reduces the theoretical inductance considerably.

In short you have created a transformer with a shorted secondary. Have you noticed that in big power inductors and transformers, steel laminates are used and, each steel laminate is insulated from each other thus reducing massively the eddy currents. Maybe you have noticed the laminates but didn't realize they were insulated from each other.

Smaller cores (such as those made from ferrite) are in fact pretty good insulators and, have very little in the way of eddy currents even at quite high frequencies. Maybe try using a ferrite rod instead: -

[image]

Image from [6 (Dia.) x 40mm Fair-Rite Ferrite Core](https://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/ferrite-cores/4674065). Ferrite rods come in many shapes and sizes of course. Here's one that is [200 mm long and 10 mm diameter](https://uk.farnell.com/ferroxcube/rod10-200-4b1/ferrite-core-cylindrical/dp/2103385)

---

The other significant problem is that you have assumed a relative permeability of 4000 and, this just won't be the case. The magnetic field forms a closed loop from one pole of the iron rod, through the rod and back through air from the other pole to the first pole. See [this diagram](https://www.sciencefacts.net/solenoid-magnetic-field.html) for instance: -

[image]

More than half the distance the field lines travel is through air. This means that the *effective* permeability is much closer to that of air and miles away from being 4000 (relative).

Comment: Thank you Andy!

Ok so a ferrite rod should not require separation to maintain close to the full permeability?

I don't know of any local distributors here in the USA, but if you had to pick between these options below what would be the best choice for an electromagnetic energy harvester (50 or 60 Hz)?

https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00UIZQFEM                           

https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00OPT6LQO           

https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/ferroxcube/ROD10-200-4B1/7651737  (this one seems to have a 12 week delivery time)

Comment: The only product I could possibly choose is one that is sold from a recognized manufacturer through a recognized distributer i.e. the 2nd one. I don't buy electronic components from unrecognizable sources as sold on ebay, amazon etc.. I will add this: a long coil is usually not as good as a bigger diameter coil that is shorter in length but, it depends on your application. If you want more help on this please don't modify your question but ask a new one because, this is a different subject.

Comment: BTW Fair-rite are a US manufacturer that should have a decent distribution presence in the US.

Comment: thank you!

I ordered 10 of these.    
https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/fair-rite-products-corp/4078377511/8594180

  I will wrapped them in a bundle of rods and then wrap a 600 turn coil around them.  That should give me I assume a measurement of around 10 H inductance.  I will post here the results.

One question though, what should I insulate the individual rods with? or should I insulate them at all?

Comment: No it won't. The formula you have used assumes a permeability of iron/ferrite but, from one pole to the other pole there is a massive, massive air gap and, the net permeability will be closer to the permeability of air. Of course this is a problem with your earlier design but, the conducting iron rod stuck out like a sore thumb and so I based my answer on that @zdanman <-- you can prove this for yourself if you make a winding that can have the ferrite rods easily removed and see the difference in inductance that occurs. It might be 2 to 5 times greater but not 400 times greater.

Comment: So... what are you saying?... that in order to get the desired inductance, the only way is a toroidal core?

Comment: A closed magnetic core won't pick up any external field so no, that's not what I'm saying.

Comment: I apologize for my ignorance. I just am trying to get a handle on what I need to order to get my desired result. So is there no possible way to design a standalone 10 H inductor?  What about half the rods inside the coil and some outside the coil and connect the two with wires?

Comment: @zdanman I don't see why you need 10 henries TBH and yes, air coils of 10 H can be made but, their purpose is very specialist. Maybe you should begin a new question fully explaining what you are trying to achieve whilst justifying the inductance value of 10 henry. I will be very interested to read it and contribute. So, on that basis, if we are done here, please take note of this: [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification.

Comment: @zdanman Toroids aren't the only option; two-piece EI cores and pot cores are popular too. Toroids are generally the best performance you can get for an inductor, but they're more work to assemble, where EI and pot cores come in two parts and are significantly easier to wind.

Comment: @hearth the trouble is this: he's wanting to couple an externally produced magnetic field to his coil and, this means that you can't use closed-ferrite cores because you can barely couple any external magnetic field to them. He's wanting to do energy harvesting and the only way is a totally open coil (hence why I used the ferrite rod as an example).

Comment: Yes exactly.  I made the post as suggested.  Thank you all!

https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/688853/electromagnetic-energy-harvester

Answer (score 4):

I suspect your issue is that iron and steel are conductive, leading to significant eddy current losses. You're seeing the effect of having shorted turns in your coil.

Comment: Thank you.  So what should I use for the core?

I was always taught that inductors and transformers use iron cores since they are so permeable.  

I guess pages such as these:    https://www.electricalvolt.com/iron-core-inductor/     are mistaken as well (?) since they advocate for a coil wrapped directly around and iron core?

Comment: @zdanman random articles on the internet being wrong sadly is more of a norm than an exception. In this case, they might have simply been imprecise: as Hearth explains very nicely, the problem is that the core it self has relatively good electrical conductivity. To counter that, iron cores are typically iron *powder* cores, not monolithic iron.

Comment: @zdanman To elaborate, iron powder cores are made of a metal powder (usually an iron alloy, not pure iron; sendust is popular) dispersed within an epoxy matrix. This structure significantly reduces conductivity. Other inductors use sintered ferrite powder; ferrites are mixed oxides of iron and other metals, which are thoroughly non-conductive and have fairly high magnetic permeability. Choosing a core material is actually a pretty complex decision with lots of tradeoffs.

Comment: @zdanman There are also laminated steel cores, which use a structure consisting of sheets of silicon steel (an alloy particularly suited to this) with insulating film in between. Provided the sheets are oriented correctly relative to the coil, this reduces eddy currents.

Comment: Thank you.  After reading that, I looked at David Chengs book and realized he briefly mentioned this on page 314 and 349.  I guess for my purposes, when the rod is parallel to power line, the magnetic flux will point perpendicular to the rod (correct?) therefore the rod would need to be split into discs (like a stack of coins) will insulating material between them all - as opposed to the usual sheets wrapped around one another.  Am I thinking about this correctly?

Comment: @zdanman No, it would need to be split into a bundle of rods. Discs would still allow eddy currents. Sheets wrapped around each other would as well.