# Electromagnetic Energy Harvester

Tags: electromagnetism, inductance, induction, energy-harvesting

It was suggested I make a new post since the topic was growing in complexity.

I am looking into constructing an inductor to utilize electromagnetic induction near a high voltage transmission line.  If I can gain a true EMF of around 12 V AC or so, I should then be able to rectify this into DC in order to power a 12 V DC LED bulb.

The observed multimeter readings so far do not seem to be reliable as they will not even power a 3 V DC LED although readings indicate voltages to be much greater as shown in one of my videos.  I believe this may be due to the large amount of electrostatic in the vicinity and so accurate readings will not be possible.  The only real test is seeing the LED light up.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ahjiVxmtgs8

Shown in the video is me holding a 1 inch x 36 inch steel rod outside of clearance of a transmission line (115kV phase-phase) with about 105 A line current running through it at the time.  This steel rod has 1100 turns of #22 enameled wire coiled around it.  You can see the multimeter picks up about 1 Vac.  After attaching the leads to a rectifier, the multimeter wildly reads up to 40 V DC depending on distance to line.

At the end of the video you can see a 3 V DC LED attached to the rectifier with the multimeter in voltage mode seeing 28 V DC on one leg of the LED.  Later, not in the video, this LED was connected between the negative and positive DC terminals of the rectifier and it did not light up.   The multimeter was connected in ammeter mode and did not detect more than a micro-amp passing through the LED.  The LED was later verified on the ground to be good and easily lit up with a AA battery connected to it.

A verified LCR meter was connected to the steel rod inductor coil and a 14 mH inductance was measured.  I have ordered 10 small ferrite rods to use as a new core.  https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/fair-rite-products-corp/4078377511/8594180

[image]

If we add more turns (8000 turns) and assume a line current of 200 A, some loose calculations seem to suggest a required 10 H inductance in order to produce an EMF of 12 V.

[image]

I am sure I am missing a lot of factors and understanding, however this seems to be an interesting idea and I wish to see it produce some sort of result.

Any suggestions or advice on how to get the most current flow from the inductor is greatly appreciated!  All transmission circuits that the inductor will be tested around will have between 100 A - 250 A line current.

The geometry of a cylindrical inductor is attractive due to the ease of turning the coil around it (as opposed to a toroidal form).

Additional Disclosure: I currently work on these power lines for a living.

Comment: Besides what Andy mentioned, you are neglecting the 3-phase effect. The magnetic fields from the 3-phases will tend to cancel each other. You want the relative distances from the 3-phases to be as large as possible. If they are stacked vertically, then you want to be directly below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *The observed multimeter readings so far do not seem to be reliable as
> they will not even power a 3 V DC LED although readings indicate
> voltages to be much greater as shown in one of my videos.*

Your idea is flawed. The lines of magnetic field that surround the conductor carrying the current (105 amps) do not flow along the length of the wire but travel [around it in circles](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/411492/electric-field-around-a-current-carrying-conductor): -

[image]

Your energy-harvesting inductor orientation is completely wrong. It should be like this: -

[image]

In the position that you showed it in your video it will pick-up no magnetic energy. The fact that you are registering a voltage on your multimeter is highly likely due to capacitive coupling from the high-voltage on the overhead cable so when you said this...

> *I believe this may be due to the large amount of electrostatic in the
> vicinity and so accurate readings will not be possible.*

... you are on the right track i.e. it's a [red-herring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_herring) and confusing the situation. Any magnetic energy-harvester this close to high-voltage power rails is going to get these side-effects.

> *Any suggestions or advice on how to get the most current flow from the
> inductor is greatly appreciated*

For a start you should test your ideas on a bench using a low voltage supply that is capable of delivering a hundred amps into a controlled short circuit. The short circuit wire can be laid on the bench and used to find the ideal position of your pick-up inductor. You **will** find that the optimum position is how I have drawn it above.

You will also find that a more ideal shape is like this: -

[image]

Comment: Yes, lots of turns, big hole. The people who managed to steal significant amounts of power from power lines had coils with huge areas.

Comment: Thank you for your masterful insight!  Concerning the core, the "short bundle of ferrite rods" approach is still the best in this scenario?

Comment: Ferrite is going to be the best. Obviously a fat single ferrite would be best but a bundle is the next best thing. Try it on a bench first if you can. You should be able to get it to work on a regular AC supply feeding a kettle but, don't forget to split live from neutral and take note what mattman said about avoiding picking up "cancelling" fields (same applies to L and N). You don't need to prove this at lethal killer voltages. Try it safely then take it further.

Comment: latest:  https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/689306/ferrite-core-inductance-similar-to-iron