# How can I calculate the current induced in the copper coil that is wrapped around a single phase of an 11kV, 2616A distribution line?

Tags: transistors, electromagnetism, arduino-uno, electric-field, distribution-network

**Aim:** To develop an alert system for power outages in the distribution line, informing electricians of their occurrence.

Working Principal:
**Fuse Monitoring**: The Arduino measures the status of the power in the distribution line using  monitoring circuit of transistors connected in a Darlington manner. When there is no power, it triggers a response in the monitoring circuitry.
**Arduino Logic and Control:** Upon detecting a popped fuse, the Arduino triggers an alert sequence.
**Alert Sequence:** The Arduino activates the GSM module to send an SMS alert via a SIM card.
It can also activate an LED as a visual alert indication.
**Power Supply:** The solar PV panel generates electricity, which charges the battery.
The battery powers the system components when sunlight is insufficient.

How can the current and voltage induced in the copper coil be calculated so that the right transistors are used? I would like to determine the base current of the transistor connected to the copper coil.

I tried to determine the current and voltage induced in the coil but I do not know which formula to use, I have almost all information about the distribution line line but then I just do not know the way to go about determining the induced voltage and current. I am expecting that the current induced in the copper coil will be amplified by the transistors and detected by the microcontroller as an indication that the is power flowing in the distribution line.

[image: sketch of system]

Comment: I sure hope this is about *calculation* only.

Comment: Whose distribution line is this? Would it not be better (let alone *safer*) to ask the power company for tips, rather than the internet? || Are you familiar with FCIs (Fault Circuit Indicators)? || No current is induced in an open-circuit coil oriented as shown; it's not clear what you're after. The detector circuit seems to imply more of an electrostatic sensor, which does not require a coil (a neighboring wire would suffice).

Comment: How will you insulate your coil from the line?

Comment: The line is insulated, so assume that my coil wouldn't have to be insulated. Have u head of a non contact voltage tester, I am trying to use the same principal. Electromagnetic Induction, Voltage induced in the copper coil causes some very small current in mA to flow to the base of the transistor, the three transistors amplifies the current and the analogue input of the Arduino Uno will be used to detect the presence of the induced voltage. Thus I will like to know if it is possible for me to calculate the induced voltage and current

Comment: If overhead power lines have any coating at all (often, there is none) then it's just for weather protection, not for electrical insulation. They are insulated by the air and, by ceramic standoffs or hangers where they are supported by poles or pylons.

Comment: Technically, the non contact testers don't use induction: they sense capacitive displacement current.

Comment: I have never encountered an overhead line with continuous isolation. To be PD free at 11 kV, it would take in the order of 10 mm coating. Which country is this in? Are you qualified to work at 11 kV?

Comment: Well, it would be electrostatic induction -- but this term is less often used these days.

Answer (score 1):

> *How can the current and voltage induced in the copper coil be
> calculated so that the right transistors are used? I would like to
> determine the base current of the transistor connected to the copper
> coil.*

Take a look at your picture: -

[image]

Clearly, one end of your coil is not connected hence, there cannot be any current flow. Then, the way you have shown the coil as looping around the distribution line conductor will mean that there is no induced voltage because the net magnetic flux in the coil is zero.

By the way, it is voltage that is induced as per Faraday's law of induction and, current may flow if the coil can circulate a current. That current flow is due to the induced voltage and the load resistor connected and, that current flow is not "induced" but flows as a result of ohm's law.

Faraday's law of induction might help you get to the bottom of this when you have designed your receive coil and circuit correctly: -

$$V = L\dfrac{di}{dt}\hspace{1cm}\text{or alternatively written as}\hspace{1cm}V=N\dfrac{d\Phi}{dt}$$

[This answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/688853/electromagnetic-energy-harvester/688854#688854) might explain how to build an energy harvesting coil.

Comment: There's capacitance between the coil and the wire, and that will surely pass detectable current.

Comment: @JohnDoty you are scraping the barrel I believe. And, if that were the case, why bother trying to design a coil (as per the question title)?

Comment: All he wants to do is detect if the wire is hot, and capacitive sensing works fine. Item of commerce: search for "voltage tester pen".

Comment: @JohnDoty that is not what the question is about --> "**voltage induced in the copper coil**" <-- it's about a coil and not a capacitor but, if you want to make an answer that advises him to use a different technology please go ahead because I'm sure it would help him.

Comment: Maybe because a coil is easy to make and mechanically stable. Ever hear of a "gimmick capacitor"?

Comment: I'm not a mind-reader but please do make an answer demonstrating the alternative method.

Comment: A coil constructed as drawn here *is* a capacitor. It's just not functioning as an inductor.

Comment: Don't make the mental error that all coils are functionally inductors.

Comment: Please make your answer and forget about trying to persuade me to think that the OP was actually talking about a capacitor.

Comment: The OP is actually talking about sensing HV, and doesn't seem to know the difference between induction and displacement current.

Comment: Actually it seems that the 3-stage Darlington circuit shown by the OP is copied from a typical non-contact AC voltage detector. See: https://www.circuits-diy.com/non-contact-ac-voltage-detector-with-circuit-diagram/

Answer (score 1):

Your coil will have some capacitance to the HV line. You can look up formulae for cylindrical capacitors to get some idea of how much based on its geometry and the dielectric constant of its insulation. But guessing 10 pF, I get an impedance of about 270 megohoms at 60 Hz. 11 kV will drive a current of about 40 microamps through that. Pretty trivial to sense. In principle, you could just clip it with diodes, feed it directly to logic.

This is, however, a terrible approach to the problem. You don't want extraneous conductors anywhere near 11 kV. This is very dangerous.

Comment: [Calculator for the Capacitance of a Cylindrical Capacitor](https://www.vcalc.com/wiki/TylerJones/Capacitance+of+a+Cylindrical+Capacitor)